# Angular Bootstrap modal - checkbox not bound to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the modal from the Angular fork of Bootstrap 3: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal and I'm trying to use a checkbox inside the modal and get its value back in my main controller.

The checkbox value is well bound in the view but not in the controller of the modal.
Here's an example of the problem: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UQFkeRvvsiXZGjCRj9IK?p=preview)

The modal controller:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.checked = false;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close( $scope.checked);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

=> $scope.checked in the ok function doesn't contain the correct value...

The view:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"> test
        </label><br/>
        Checked: {{checked}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Any idea?

Thanks by advance

Comment: It doesn't seem like calling `$modalInstance.close` with a boolean works very well. If I put a String in there it works. No idea why.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem comes from that, I tried to use String inside the checkbox and it still doesn't work: http://plnkr.co/edit/uY44SiNdcI2Atp6pVWhq?p=preview

Comment: That's not what I meant. If you do `$modalInstance.close('Hi, I am a String');` that works. See yarons, answer where he uses an object instead of a boolean. That's working around this exact problem.

Comment: You should probably ask the maintainers of UI Bootstrap if this is a bug or a feature. The docs does not say anything about using boolean primitives in the close function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dirty trick that [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/3r3Z10f30b75USZKrnsW?p=preview) is to put the `checked` parameter inside an object.

```
$scope.checked = {c:false};

$scope.ok = function () {
  $modalInstance.close( $scope.checked.c);
};
```

Comment: Indeed this works! I accept the answer even if I think this is not working as it should... :/

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the checked value straight as a parameter of the function, this is a little workaround for bypassing the lack of the binding between the modal view and the associated controller:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok(checked)">OK</button>
```

And then pass it as function parameter in the controller:

```
$scope.ok = function (result) {
       $modalInstance.close( result);
};
```

Full working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Qp8Lddz8VbW9x9Z4DMI?p=preview)